# Fixing tab bar in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying have fixed Tabs component at the bottom of the screen. I have tried

```
<Tabs
  contentContainerStyle={{position: "fixed"}}
>
</Tabs>
```

and even `style={{position:"fixed"}}`

How do I fix the Tabs at the bottom?

Comment: I guess you'd need {{position:fixed;bottom:0px;}}

Comment: Sorry I might want to clarify: position:fixed doesn't fix the tabs.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping tabs in a div? `<div style={{ position: fixed; bottom: 0 }}><Tabs /></div>`

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

```
<div style={{position: "fixed", bottom:"0", width:"100%"}}>
 <Tabs>
   <Tab icon={<ActionFlightTakeoff />} />
     <Tab icon={<ActionFlightTakeoff />} />
     <Tab icon={<ActionFlightTakeoff />} />
   </Tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: The following setup works visually, however the event listeners and active tab indicator where unexpectedly render useless.

Answer (score 2):

I use the tabItemContainerStyle like this:

```
<code>
    <Tabs tabItemContainerStyle={{position: "fixed", bottom:"0"}}>
    </Tabs>
</code>
```

Comment: Do explain, how this fixed it as well.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.